# Ionic Framework won't authenticate in browser (works in emulator)

Tags: 7, services

I've set up a simple Ionic Framework app which utilises Drupal 7 Services API to authenticate a user, before hitting some custom end points to retrieve data when logged in.

The issue I'm seeing is when running `ionic serve` to view the app in the browser: `http://localhost:8100/#/auth/login`.  I can successfully log in, but when requesting an endpoint, the user is not detected as authenticated.

1. Logging in successfully - see log debug:
   [image: 1. I can log in successfully]
2. However, when trying to access a custom end point - the user doesn't appear to be authenticated - the dblog reveals `Anonymous (not verified)`, thus returning `["Access denied for user anonymous"]` in the console. The dblog looks like so:
   [image]

The odd thing is, if performing the *exact* same steps using POSTMAN or via the iOS emulator when running `ionic emulate ios` all works fine, see dblog now (this is when using emulator):
[image]

More info: I'm using the Drupal `CORS` module, with the following set up:
`api/*|http://localhost:8100|*|Content-Type,X-CSRF-Token,Authentication, Origin, Cookie|true`

On each request I'm passing the `X-CSRF-Token`.  I can't pass a `Cookie` as the console returns `'Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"`

My `$http` request looks as follows:

```
  this.getEventFeed = function(csrf, payload) {
    var api = FetchGlobals.getUrl();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: api + '/api/rest/event_feed/feed.json',
     headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token' : csrf,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
      // 'Cookie' : cookie,
      'Authentication' : cookie
     },
     data: payload,
     // json : true,
    }
    console.log(req);
    $http(req)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      var response = {
        'ok' : true,
        'data' : data,
      };
      deferred.resolve(response);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      var response = {
        'status' : status,
        'data' : data,
      };
      deferred.resolve(response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

EDIT: It appears to be an issue with the Cookie. As recommended here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1133084#comment-8433677 - I've added a new header called `Authentication`.  I can see from the dblog the user is succesfully being authenticated, however, I receive the error `["CSRF validation failed"]`.

Comment: what was the problem I am not getting?

Comment: The user is not being authenticated when hitting an endpoint - if you see the screenshots - you can see all the calls are being made by anonymous.  Apart from the last screen shot, you can see user is not anonymous and the results are returned successfully.  Only appears to be an issue when running the app via the browser.  If the same requests are made in POSTMAN or via emulator, it works!

Comment: You probably need to run in the same port as your Drupal site, otherwise you'll need to enable CORS.

Answer (score 2):

Incase someone faces a similar issue, I managed to find a fix by:

1. Setting up an `ionic proxy` see: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/
2. Sending the `Cookie` with the headers as `Authentication` to bypass the issue `'Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie`.  Then adding this code on `hook_init()` https://www.drupal.org/node/1133084#comment-8433677.